# Weird ratio of favorite questions in "interesting"

Tags: support, bug, homepage

I want to say sorry for possible wrong use of SO terms, and this could be the reason why I can't find this question on meta - I'm not sure how to properly call the things I want to ask about.

For the last year I've been participating on SO only in [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala) tag. I'm not interested in others, because I participate in SO mostly for my own education and I am learning scala intensively. So what I did is when I load SO page each day, I clicked on [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala) in *Favourite Tags* (or find this tag anywhere else on the page), and just looked through questions, trying to answer some of them.

Recently I started to extend my expertise to [playframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playframework), [akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka) and others. So I would like to view all these questions together with [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala), and some of the questions that are asked about [playframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playframework) or [akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka) are not marked with [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala), because these frameworks work on other platforms. So what I did is I included all the tags I'm interested in, in *Favorite Tags*. Unfortunately now my dashboard looks like this:

[image]

Most of the questions are not related to the topics I've chosen. In fact, out of 100 questions displayed, I could count only 15 questions related to the topic (questions with yellow background)

I understand that this is probably due to the tags I've set are unpopular and have little questions produced each day. But I still do not want to see all the stuff I am not interested in.

So:

1. Can I somehow turn off the option to show unrelated to *Favorite Tags* questions in the dashboard?
2. If (1) is a policy, and I cannot do that, could you fix the ratio of yellow/white questions to be stable in terms of how many yellow questions are present, and not in the popularity of the questions?

Comment: I think that the text on the front page tab should be changed from "interesting" to "random crap".

Comment: \\(^.^)/ I support that title

Comment: @Lundin:  The only common attribute of highlighted questions that I've noticed is that they're almost always severely downvoted.  I was really surprised to see the CSS styled them `tagged-interesting`... unless it was using the "train wreck in progress" definition of "interesting".  (The new questions page itself doesn't even hint why some posts are highlighted, which is why I went searching for enlightenment in the CSS.)

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase "tagged-interesting" just means the question is tagged with one or more tags that you've favorited. It isn't a value judgement.

Comment: @duskwuff:  That would explain a lot of the downvotes I've seen on those questions...  "Which language should I learn so I can write my new Face Book killer?  [java] [javascript] [php] [ada] [forth] [whitespace] [uml] [xml] [ascii] [bytes] [bits]"

Answer (score 18):

Instead of using the dashboard with Favorite Tags, you can search by tags:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala+or+playframework+or+akka

Comment: This is a great link and I'll probably use it, thanks. But I still think this should be integrated somehow in SO user interface. Right now both `interesting` and `favorite questions` panels are useless to me

Comment: I think there sould be a more native way for this common task. Maybe a `Followed Tag` Tab

Answer (score 0):

The "Interesting" tab is a bit of a misnomer. It displays most questions that have had recent activity in reverse chronological order, regardless of whether they are likely to be interesting *to you*.

(There appear to be some questions that are not displayed in that view, even though they have had recent activity. I'm not sure what causes this, and would appreciate some clarification!)

Setting tags as "favorite" just causes posts with those tags to show up with a yellow highlight -- like the "Break statement not working" question in your screenshot. Similarly, setting tags as "ignored" doesn't make their questions disappear entirely; it just makes them appear a bit dull and faded. As far as I'm aware, neither of these settings has any other effects on which posts you see on the site.

Comment: I had no idea it works like that. Isn't it a bit misleading? The tab is called "interesting". And given the comments in this topic it seems that there are little people using it. I actually think I can remember the time (but I might be mistaken) when SO had the behavior of interesting something like I'm describing. I have no idea why that was changed if my memory is true

Answer (score -5):

The alternative is a feed that could go a whole hour without changing much. There could be a flag set for it, but it won't lead to you seeing more of what you want to see.

Also, it's in Stack Overflow's interest to encourage its users to read and answer questions. By showing you more questions, you're more likely to help this goal. Stack Overflow doesn't want a user coming to the site and not seeing anything new.

Comment: I can't agree with that. Scala receives about 4-8 new questions in an hour, it's changing, just slowly. But instead I receive a feed in which 85% is not interesting for me. Instead of going through a feed full of stuff I do not want to answer and try searching the stuff I can answer, I can just abandon answering at all. This is the same as proposing to show every user feed of every questions without any filters, because who know what user will answer what question

Comment: I've edited my question to reflect that it's more active than originally thought. I still believe that going hours without much change in the feed is not ideal at the least and is something Stack Overflow is hesitant to offer.